# How do I turn off audio echo from microphone to local speakers?

Tags: 11.10, 11.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

From 2 microphone inputs I have only one in use. When I talk into my USB microphone the audio echoes back to my local speakers (my "hello" is getting looped back instantly).

How do I turn this off?

Additional information on how to do this from command line (for a remote machine) would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Sound Settings (GUI)

In *"Sound Settings..."* choose *Hardware* and change from *"Analog Stereo **Duplex**"* from the *Profile* selection to *"Analog Stereo **Input**"* for usage as microphone or *"Analog Stereo **Output**"* for use as speakers.

[image]

---

#### Command line

From the command line we need to know the `index` and possible `profiles` of cards installed. Both will be listed with

```
pacmd list-cards
```

To change the card profile we may issue

```
pacmd set-card-profile <index> <profile>
```

Where we have to give appropriate values for the card-index we want to set up, and the profile desired.

#### Examples

The following examples show the commands for a standard internal audio card with index `0` for values corresponding to the GUI:

```
pacmd set-card-profile 0 input:analog-stereo  # for Input
pacmd set-card-profile 0 output:analog-stereo  # for Output
pacmd set-card-profile 0 output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo # for Duplex
```

Comment: many many thanks just one request (i missed to mention that). Is this possible to do remotely using SSH command line? (unfortunately my laptop i can change but i am connected to a remote PC). Can i do the exact same thing with any tools or command line please?

Comment: I tried this exactly how you explained. But still i have ECHO myself in my own Speaker.

Comment: Added command line solution. Take care to select the appropriate card index for your USB device, and for the card you attached the speakers.