# Turn off audio loopback from microphone

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, microphone

I just set up my machine and plugged in my headset, but now I'm currently wondering how to disable the audio loopback from my microphone.

I've found nearly the same question over here

[How do I turn off audio echo from microphone to local speakers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94854/how-do-i-turn-off-audio-echo-from-microphone-to-local-speakers)

But my Interface looks different, and there are a hell lot of entries if run

```
pacmd list
```

So I'm not sure wich one to pick.

Comment: Hmm... I'd like to set up audio loop back : ) Anyone done it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The link in your question disables the mic, and in my case it even didn't help, the mic became disabled for applications, but the echoing stayed. What I've done to solve this:

1. Open `alsamixer` in terminal.
2. Press <kbd>F3</kbd> to make sure you are on the playback tab.
3. Find any interesting setting there for "Mic" or "Capture" which shouldn't be there, since we are on the playback tab.
4. Either mute that volume meter by pressing <kbd>M</kbd> or lower its level to zero with the cursor keys.

   Now it shouldn't echo back, and recording with the mic should be also possible.
5. If it still echos back, then you have to mute the mic volumes, just go back to `alsamixer` press <kbd>F4</kbd> and mute what you have to on the capture tab.

Comment: For me it was `alsamixer` -> press F6 -> select correct soundcard, e.g. intel PCA -> for me there are like 10 volume meters showing and more are to the right, like 20 in total. One is called `Loopback` which instead of a volume meter only shows `Enabled`. Select that one with left / right arrow and then switch to `Disabled` by pressing down arrow. The change should apply immediately.

Comment: Wow, was trying to figure this duplex echo of my recording in QTractor for hours... Now in alsamixer `F4` - I decreased "Capture 1" to zero, and increased "Capture" instead. No more echo :-) Thank you!

Comment: For me with my Logitech Stereo H650e headset it wa a case of running `alsamixer`, hitting `F6`, choosing the `Logitech Stereo H650e` and adjusting the `Sidetone` input. Increasing or decreasing the volume meant I could hear myself clearly in my own headset, and muting that input (`M`) fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone facing this, I had same issue in Ubuntu 18.04, and was resolved by changing Settings -> Sound -> Output -> Profile (drop down selection) and used 'High Fidelity Playback' instead of 'Headset Head Unit'

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to speak and hear a game's sound at the same time, for which I had to set `Speaker<whatever>` to 0 in `alsamixer` (but don't wonder if your speakers are muted subsequently … you know how to fix that ! ;) )