# How do i disable Logitech G430 sidetone/mic monitoring/listening?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, microphone, logitech

On windows I got to Settings then sounds, then recording, then advanced, then toggle listen OFF. Then that works and makes it so I cant hear my self.

Tried running the logitech gaming software with wine no success and there is no loopback module running.

Kernel: 4.19.36-1-MANJARO
OS: Manjaro Linux x86_64

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is a stock Ubuntu forum. Please ask the question at https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

[Turn off audio loopback from microphone](https://askubuntu.com/questions/393234/turn-off-audio-loopback-from-microphone)

Assuming you want to mute playback but not the mic itself, this thread has the solution.

Press f6 to navigate to the g430 soundcard once you're in the menu, then arrow keys to select playback and arrow down.