# Recently installed ubuntu can hear myself through microphone

Tags: sound, usb

Ok so i recently installed Ubuntu and i got my headset Logitech g430s and I can hear  myself through my headphones when i talk. How can I fix this it's really annoying.

Comment: Do you have a "Duplex" audio profile activated? See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/94854/how-do-i-turn-off-audio-echo-from-microphone-to-local-speakers

Answer (score 0):

Go to your sound settings and mute the microphone input.

Comment: Mutting the sound only made it so my friends counldnt hear me